# text-decoration-color not working for IE

Tags: css

I there any alternative for `text-decoration-color` for IE? I google but haven't got any solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick google search cleared up that `text-decoration-color: ;` is supported by IE

Comment: is there any alternative for it? @D3nj1

Comment: @D3nj1: Where does it say that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms531165(v=vs.94)

Comment: @SagarKharche Not to my knowledge, i don't work with IE ^^

Comment: @D3nj1: That's text-decoration, not text-decoration-color.

Comment: @BoltClock ahh my bad, well if you want to change the color of the text, use Color: red; for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see code bellow:

```css
div {
  color: blue; 
  text-decoration: underline;
}
span{
color:black;
}
```

```html
<div><span>underline below me!</span></div>
```

**IE** does not support `text-decoration-color`:https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-color/